# Unsolvable events scenario in RavenDB?

Tags: indexing, lucene.net, ravendb

**Edit**. Here's a simplified description of the issue:
I have events

```
class Event { Id = 0, Dates = new DateTime[] {} }
```

I need to query for all events within a date range for example (august 1 to october 20). The result shall list uniqe events within this range **ordered by date**. Like this:

```
Event one   2012-08-04,2012-09-06,2012-09-10
Event two   2012-10-02
etc.
```

I need to be able to page this result. That's it.

---

I have the following issue with my events using ravendb. I have a document (representing an event) that contains an array of dates, for example 2012-08-20, 2012-08-21, 2012-09-14, 2013-01-05 etc.

```
class Event { Dates = []; }
```

I have a few criteria that must be met:

1. I need to be able to query these documents on a date range. For example find all events that has any date between august 1 and september 22, or october 1 and october 3.
2. I must be able to sort the query on date
3. I must be able to page the result.

Seems easy enough right? Well I have had two approaches to this but they both fail.

Create an index with multiple from. Like so:

```
from event in docs.Events
from date in event.Dates
select new { Dates = date}
```

This works and is easy to query. However it can't be paged because of skippedresults (the index will contain duplicates of each event). And sorting also fails in combination with paging.

...............

Create a simple index

```
from event in docs.Events
select new { Dates = event.Dates }
```

This also works and is simple to query, it can also be paged. However it cannot be sorted. I need to sort the documents by the first available date within the queried range.

If I can't solve this it will probably be a deal breaker for us.. and I really don't want to get started with a new application, besides I really like RavenDB..

Comment: How would this be sorted if an event contained multiple dates that satisfied your date range criteria (does that occur higher than another event that has only a single match on the date range)? If multiple events satisfy the date criteria identically (both have a single date out of their array that is on the same day), how should they be sorted?

Comment: If two events occur on the same date within the queried range they can be sorted on whatever. That's a luxury problem for now.

Comment: KINDA SOLVED: After some talking with Oren on ravendb mailing list the best solution seems to be the first approach here. However there was a bug in RavenDB regarding skippedresults which has now been fixed. However this solution only allows me to get next and previous page.

Comment: I have the same use case, but I really need to be able to skip ahead several pages (i.e. the pager contains clickable page numbers), so the first solution isn't really working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final solution for this was creating both indexes. We needed both indexes anyway in our application so it wasn't any overhead.

The following index is used for querying and paging. Take() and Skip() works for this one:

```
from event in docs.Events
from date in event.Dates
select new { Date = date}
```

However the above index does NOT return the correct number of total hits, which you need for creating a pager. So we create another index:

```
from event in docs.Events
select new { Date = event.Dates }
```

Now we can run the exact same query (note that the Date field has the same name on both indexes) on the above index using Statistics() and Take(0) to only get the number of hits.

The downside to this is obviously that you need to run two queries, but I haven't found a way around that.

Comment: Yes, provided that the index is consistent between the two queries, which depending on your application's write-intensity may be more or less likely. Otherwise you might get the wrong numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement (recurring events), with the added twist that the number of dates was highly variable (could be from 1 to the hundreds) and may be associated with a venue.

I ended up storing event dates in an EventOccurrence after coming to a similar impasse:

```
public class EventOccurrence {   
   public string EventId {get; set;}   
   public DateTime Start {get; set;}   
   public string VenueId {get; set;} 
}
```

Its easily queryable and sortable, and using Session.Include on the occurrence we still retain query performance.

It seems like a reversion to the relational model, but it was the correct choice given our constraints.

Comment: Interesting approach. So you create a document for each date in an event, then query those documents, doing an include on the actual events? But that way you'll get a hit on an event for each date it has, how do you solve paging?

Comment: I had to do it that way because of the type of queries i expected. As to multiple hits per event - not really. Raven Sessions have a first level cache so if an item already exists in the cache, no additional round trip is made to the server. There is only one access per distinct event, and with Include that happens on the server anyway. As for paging, that's fairly easy in Raven. What specific question do you have.

Comment: This seems like it could be the way to go. Would you mind sharing your index-solution? It seems rather complex.

Comment: I've been looking a bit at this, but I can't figure out how to do both paging and sorting.. for paging I need to group on eventid and for sorting I need to group on date. If you could help me out I'd be very grateful.

Comment: I've been looking at this solution too but can't see how paging would be solved. If there is a way, we both fail to see it. You don't know how many EventOccurrences you'd need to fetch to get, say, 20 unique events.

Answer (score 0):

You're saying that the "simple index" approach works except for sorting right?

```
from event in docs.Events
select new
{
  Dates = event.Dates,
  FirstDate = event.Dates.First()
}
```

Then you can sort on FirstDate. You can't sort on analyzed or tokenized fields.

Comment: This was actually an early solution for me. But this does not work. For example Event1 { 2012-01-10, 2012-03-03 } Event2 { 2012-03-01 } Search from 2012-03-01 to 2012-03-05. Event1 will be sorted first since it's first date is before Event2.